# Como utilizar Sass em servidor

Tags: sass

Como leigo ainda em Sass, tenho a dúvida de como utilizá-lo em um provedor como por exemplo locaweb ou hostgator. Eles precisam ter suporte a Sass ou tem outra forma?

Comment: Você pode fazer a edição local com SASS e na WEB você faz upload apenas do arquivo .css, não precisa ter os outros arquivos para que o estilo funcione sendo que ele já estará todo unificado no arquivo .css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara qualquer servidor vc pode hospedar um arquivo `.sass` ou `.scss` ou `.less`. Mas o que não vai acontecer é o serviço de hospedagem compilar seus aquivos para `.css` de forma que o browser consiga renderiza-lo.

O Browser por contra própria não consegue compilar aquivos desse tipo (`.sass`/`.scss`/`.less`) em um `.css`. O que vc pode fazer é usar algum tipo de `WebPack` (https://webpack.js.org/) ou `JetPack` para que na hora que vc for publicar o seu site no host ele já compile o seu `.scss` em `.css` antes de enviar para o FTP

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> ***Nunca ouvi falar de alguma hospedagem que compile CSS...***

Comment: Nem precisa de webpack ou similares, existem os compiladores só de sass.

Comment: @bfavaretto sim claro, o que eu queria falar eh que ele já pode subir tudo para o host já compilando e otimizando o que precisar. Não sei se tem compilador apenas de sass que já gera um pacote e envia pro host de forma automatizada